# select top 2 based on one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks something like this:

```
Name    LastN   DOB    EntryDate<br>
John    Smith   2015   21/02/2012<br>
John Smith      2015   26/04/2012<br>
John Smith      2015   27/05/2012<br>
Karen Eps 2015        29/08/2012<br>
Karen Eps 2015        23/05/2014<br>
Karen Eps 2015        12/02/2012
```

I need a query that pulls out the 2 latest date for each name? So the output would look something like:

```
Name    LastN   DOB    EntryDate<br>
John Smith      2015   26/04/2012<br>
John Smith      2015   27/05/2012<br>
Karen Eps 2015        29/08/2012<br>
Karen Eps 2015        23/05/2014<br>
```

Many thanks for any help with this! Please be kind,I am new to SQL :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Name, LastName order by EntryDate desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct firstname,lastname,b.*
             from yourtable t
                             cross apply(
                                select top 2 entrydate from yourtable t1
                               where t1.firstname=t.firstname                                        
                                         and t1.lastname=t.lastname 
                                             order by entrydate desc)b
```